# A peculiar bug while reading and printing strings of *char in C

Tags: c, string, pointers

I've just encountered something really odd. My string of char (let's call it `word`) turns out to have additional letters when I print it. 
 The contatenated letter varies depending on:

1. the length of the proper prefix word.
2. the number of spaces after the word.

I'm parsing the `word` from a `line` which is just a one line form the standard input. I'm using a function `readWord` to get the `word` out of the `line`:

```
void readWord(char **linePointer, char **wordPointer){
  char *line  = *linePointer;
  char *word = *wordPointer;
  while (!isEndOfLine(line) && isLowerCaseLetter(*line)){
    *word = *line;
    word++;
    line++;
  }
  word++;
  *word = '\0';
  printf("The retrieved word is: %s.\n", *wordPointer)
  *linePointer = line;
}
```

My inputs/outputs look like this (please note that I call the `readWord` function AFTER taking care of `insert` and the whitespace between):

```
// INPUT 1 :
insert foo
insert ba      // several spaces after 'ba'
// OUTPUT 2:
The retrieved word is foo.
The retrieved word is bas.

// INPUT 1 :
insert foo
insert ba      // several spaces after 'bar'
// OUTPUT 2:
The retrieved word is foo.
The retrieved word is bare.
```

I was thinking whether I allocate the `*word` properly and I guess I do:

```
root.word = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char *)); //root is my structure
```

<strike>Moreover, it is unlikely connected to some errors of reassigning the `word` string because it is completely clear at the beginning of the `readWord()` function.</strike>

Thank you for any help. It is indeed a challenging bug for me and I don't know what else I can do.

**UPDATE**

It turns out that I actually have some problems with allocating/reassigning, since:

```
//INPUT
insert foo//no spaces
  insert bar                //spaces here
//OUTPUT
word variable before calling readWord function: ' '.
The retrieved word is foo.
word variable before calling readWord function: 'insert foo
'.
The retrieved word is bare.
```

Comment: You need to allocate enough memory for the string you operate on. You don't do that.

Comment: the `word++` after the loop is one too many

Comment: @rpattiso Thanks! That's true. However `word` is not cleared after the first line, so there is more than only a one bug. I'll work on what @milleniumbug said.

Comment: Enable all compiler warnings. Follow up every warning about pointer indirection, for example in this inconsistency `while (!isEndOfLine(line) && isLowerCaseLetter(*line))`. And add a `;` at the end of the `printf()` line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never trust your input, so check for spaces to go to the beginning of the word.

You increment word one too many, as @rpattiso notes.

I have doubts about your memory allocation (you don't show us all your code):
`root.word = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char *));` allocates room for a *pointer* to a char, but does not allocate the room for the characters themselves. readWord can do that.

The following adapted version should work (updated):

```
void readWord(char **linePointer, char **wordPointer){
    char *line  = *linePointer;
    int i;

    while (!isEndOfLine(line) && !isLowerCaseLetter(*line)) line++; // go to begin of word
    *linePointer= line;
    while (!isEndOfLine(line) &&  isLowerCaseLetter(*line)) line++; // go to end of word

    i= line - *linePointer;                     // allocate room for word and copy it
    *wordPointer= malloc((i+1) * sizeof(char));
    strncpy(*wordPointer, *linePointer, i);
    (*wordPointer)[i]= '\0;

    printf("The retrieved word is: %s.\n", *wordPointer);
    *linePointer = line;
}
```

Comment: I see a big bug. I post an update (Error in strncopy)

Comment: Actually, the code does not work for one-letter-long words: `insert v` throws the `segmentation fault 11`. It crashes when it tries to run the `*wordPointer[i]= '\0'` line.

Comment: Sorry, that should be `(*wordPointer)[i]= '\0';`.